# I am Using orbit-jquery-image-slider plugin with plugin is image is not sliding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i m using  orbit-jquery-image-slider plugin i can able give fade effect by  doing this 'animation': 'fade' but not able slide image i tried to use 'animation': 'horizontal-push' but not working please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#featured').orbit({
            'animation': 'horizontal-push',
            'bullets': true,
            advanceSpeed: 10000,
        });
        $('.slider-navs').css('position', 'relative');
        $('#featured').css('width', '650px');
        $('#featured').css('height', '210px');

    });

</script>
<div class="holder">
    <div class="above_cont_area " style="height:50px;height: 219px;width: 650px;margin-left: 25px;margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <div id="featured">
            <img src="dummy-images/img1.jpg" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img2.jpg" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img3.jpg" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img4.jpg" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img5.png" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img6.png" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img7.png" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img8.png" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="dummy-images/img9.png" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is it showing any error?

Comment: i dont need fade effect i need horizontal-push effect but that is not working (i put fade effect that is working)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin requires all the image have the same size. Do the added images have the same size? The official website is [here](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin)

The orbit function will dynamically determine the height and width of your set of images and scale accordingly, but make sure all your images are the same size or the larger images will peek out on the sides.

Comment: ya all images are in same size but slide effect is not working (but fade effect is working)

Comment: I have just copy your orbit function code to replace the demo page of the plugin demo. It's works fine. May be the issue is cause by the other codes of your project.

Comment: It's tested under IE8 and Firefox.

Comment: I encounter your problem... you need to press **ctrl+F5** to reload the page without cache!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fade effect means you have to give the animation as fade only not horizontal-push

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#featured').orbit({
            'animation': 'fade',
            'bullets': true,
            advanceSpeed: 10000
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky catch 22, is that the .orbit-timer and .orbit-progress bar can't be hidden from the DOM with display none or the slideshow stops functioning.

See the following

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1856#issuecomment-19422603